# Browserify shim jquery expose doesn't process a lib while working fine on another

Tags: browserify-shim

I'm facing a problem with exposing global `jquery` to several `npm` loaded non-commonjs libs.

I have a following `jquery` expose config in package.json:

```
"browserify-shim": {
"jquery": "global:jQuery",
...
```

And I'm trying to apply this to this [datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) from eonasdan that has a common-js dependency resolving:

```
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD is used - Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery', 'moment'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    factory(require('jquery'), require('moment'));
} else {
```

But the compiled file doesn't replace `require('jquery')` with a global variable construct as it happens in all the rest of files including other libs, like this compiled bootstrap-slider for example:

```
if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery"], factory);
}
else if(typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    var jQuery;
    try {
        jQuery = (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['jQuery'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['jQuery'] : null);
    }
    catch (err) {
        jQuery = null;
    }
    module.exports = factory(jQuery);
}
```

What could possibly be a reason of this lib being such exceptional?

Does the depth of require chain matter for browserify-shim? 
Cause the slider is being required in the main bundling file, while datepicker is a dependency of dependency of a bundle (3rd level)

Comment: I ended up looking [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js) and reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835954/configure-a-generic-jquery-plugin-with-browserify-shim), and I'm wondering whether browserify-shim applies it's config in all the dependencies too; have you declared jquery as a dependency for the libraries you use?

Comment: Yes I've been trying to shim this lib declaring jQ as a dependency, but as you can see, the lib is actually CommonJS compatible and does resolve well un-shimmed (with exception for require('jquery') replacement). For now I've solved the problem by dropping jquery expose approach, just made all the application sections to rely onto single bundle that holds 100% of scripts loaded (well, except for analytics and alike)

Comment: Identical problem with Magnific Popup.