# How to get Magnific Popup working with Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm trying to get Magnific Popup to work alongside Browserify and I can't seem to get it to work. I don't have an in depth knowledge of the Browserify setup. 
All I keep getting is the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cache.$btn_enlarge.magnificPopup is not a function
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

Thanks, 
Tom

Comment: How do you add magnific-popup.js to the project?

Comment: Magnific Popup has been added via NPM and is included using:

`modal = require('magnific-popup')`

Comment: Are you sure that you initialized jQuery before and `cache.$btn_enlarge` is a jQuery element?

Comment: Yeah the entire module is:

'// #Begin banner.js
var $ = require('jquery'),
 modal = require('magnific-popup'),
    cache = require('./cache');

function init()
{
  uiBinding();
}

function uiBinding()
{
 cache.$btn_enlarge.magnificPopup({
  preloader: true,
  items: {
   src: $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src')
  },
  type: 'image',
  callbacks: {
   open: function() {

   }
  }
 })

}

module.exports = function() {

    return init();

};
// #End banner.js'

Comment: Is `$(document).ready` ? when you call this module?

Comment: Yeah within app.js document ready is fired to init the modules. I have other plugins working fine, I can't seem to get this or Photoswipe to work with Browserify. I found this on stack overflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616028/browserify-shim-jquery-expose-doesnt-process-a-lib-while-working-fine-on-anothe#_=_

Which suggests there could be a problem with Magnific Popup, but I could barking up the wrong tree! Just trying to get to the bottom of what the problem is, doesn't seem straight forward!

Comment: Anyone able to shed any light on this? @DmitriyNevzorov

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything possible with the dist files — even with a shim. I ended up realising that the code it's wrapped in (see Gruntfile.js) makes it incompatible with Gulp and Browserify. Instead concat (either manually or with Gulp) the files in the src/js folder in this order:

**core.js**

**inline.js**

**ajax.js**

**image.js**

**zoom.js**

**iframe.js**

**gallery.js**

**retina.js**

It will work then. I've packaged the files for the latest release here if you want them: https://github.com/texelate/magnificPopupGulpBrowserify/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)

```
npm install browserify-shim --save-dev
```

package.json

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "./path/to/magnific-popup.js": "magnific-popup",
}
```