# Testing javascript code that uses require('jquery') in node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, testing

I am developing a node module that uses `jQuery`'s `Deferred`s and can't figure out the best way to test it.

The file `src/MyModule.js` looks like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

var MyModule = module.exports = function() {
    // constructor
};
// other module methods that use $.Deferred()
```

Example test code in `test/MyModuleTest.js`:

```
var test = require('tape');
var MyModule = require('../src/MyModule');

test('promise test', function(t) {
    t.plan(1);

    var module = new MyModule();
    var promise = module.promiseReturningMethod();
    promise.done(function() {
        t.ok(true);
    });
    module.resolveThePromise();
});
```

I would like to simply execute the tests like this: `node test/MyModuleTest.js`.

The code will eventually be passed through Browserify which will [shim the `require('jquery')` so it uses the global jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835954/configure-a-generic-jquery-plugin-with-browserify-shim). My problem is how do I get the `require('jquery')` call from `MyModule.js` to work in the tests?

Running the test code currently gives the error:

```
TypeError: $.Deferred is not a function
```

This is because `require('jquery')` requires a window object to actually create the jQuery object. Otherwise, an empty object is returned.

I know I can use the following to make `require('jquery')` work **in the test**:

```
var myWindow = require('jsdom').jsdom().defaultView;
var $ = require('jquery')(myWindow);
```

This could be part of an answer but it's not the answer by itself! The code in `MyModule.js` should not have to hack around its `require('jquery')` call. The test code or infrastructure should somehow take care of this. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept the require() call from your test file, using the [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) package:

```
// test.js
var mock = require('mock-require');

var myWindow = require('jsdom').jsdom().defaultView;
var $ = require('jquery')(myWindow);

mock('jquery', $);
mock.reRequire('jquery'); // This will prevent require() calls to return the
                          // originally cached version of jQuery

// When MyModule will require("jquery"), it will get the one which uses jsdom's window
var MyModule = require("./MyModule.js");
```